# "Best Ways" is Subjective?

Tags: discussion

Quote from [this question](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/22/63):

> [...]  What are the best ways you've found to market yourself as a freelancer [...]

"Best ways" are quite subjective. Should we consider this question off-topic? I can't see any clear criteria for picking one answer as the accepted/right answer over any others.

Comment: These question(what is the best type) are non-constructive, and I vote to close as such (if i have that privilege ) but i am agree with jmort

Answer (score 6):

I edited the question to focus more on the actual problem that the asker is trying to solve. He's not really looking for folks to just simply come in and post their favorite way to market themselves; instead, the asker has a specific set of circumstances that makes it difficult to market himself as a freelancer. This is a challenge that an expert freelancer can answer definitively.

I made a suggested edit to change the last part of the question to be:

> As someone who works full time, how can I market myself as a freelancer in a way that gets results and that doesn't take constant maintenance to keep up?

This helps hammer home what it is that we, as answerers, need to focus on when answering the question. It also contains more keywords that others with the same problem may search for.  As an example, I'm a full time worker who also does contract work. Thus, the problems I face are quite similar to the ones this person faces.

Lastly, keep in mind subjective questions are not bad. We just need to make sure we answer them with facts, references, and specific expertise that explains why the answer is the correct answer and includes how one might approach the problem. See [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).